# How do I create outlook addin to show read receipt on action items of sent email?

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an add-in to implement tracking an email using lead-boxer(https://leadboxer.com/) where I can get all the details of the user who has opened my email. I had implemented the add-in to send an email with an image tag with the link. So I am getting the details of users.

Now I want to add a read receipt kind of action item button on the sent email and I am not getting any solution, I want to show that icon with sent email action items which is shown here(https://i.ibb.co/nwQRMzC/Capture.png).

I had tried creating another add-in but I could not find any way to place that button on the required place i.e. with email action items.

Also, I want to make a call to API when email sender opens the sent email to check if the recipient has opened that email or not.

Comment: Interesting, I read alot, but didnt figure this out

Comment: In Outlook for Windows, the add-in icon is supposed to appear in ribbon, and cannot show up in Reply/Reply All/Forward panel. There is no such JavaScript API for Office to check if the recipient has opened the email or not, but you can check with EWS API, and make a call with makeEwsRequestAsync if it does.

Comment: Thanks @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I will surely look at it. I am still confused about one thing. Can we show the outlook add-in task pane automatically on email item open? (i.e. I want to show all email tracking info in a task pane which gets opened on selecting sent email)

Comment: You add pinning support to your add-in. Once a user launches and add-in they can pin the add-in so that next time add-in task pane will show. This should get you closer to what you want. We will also appreciate if you can add your feature request to user voice. Feature requests on user voice are one of the inputs to our quarterly planning process.

Comment: Sure I will add one, also thanks for the suggestion it is helpful as anything else is not working, this will solve half of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook doesn't provide anything for customizing the reading pane action buttons. However, you may create your own form instead if you develop a COM add-in. So, you need to develop a COM add-in to be able to customize the Outlook as much as you want. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) to get started quickly. Web add-ins provide a limited capability for UI customization.

Comment: Agreed, but its also important to note that COM add-ins do not work on Web and Outlook for Mac.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful as I had some requirements which were not compatible with COM add-in. I ended up creating a custom ribbon button to perform the action.